# MySQL's STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL if called with only a time component

Tags: mysql

I came across some weirdness with MySQL's function `STR_TO_DATE()`. It seems to not be able to parse times, like so:

It works on a full string:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('08/07/16 11:59 AM', '%m/%d/%y %l:%i %p');
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('08/07/16 11:59 AM', '%m/%d/%y %l:%i %p') |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 2016-08-07 11:59:00                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Date only works:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('08/07/16', '%m/%d/%y');
+-------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('08/07/16', '%m/%d/%y') |
+-------------------------------------+
| 2016-08-07                          |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Time only doesn't:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('11:59 AM', '%l:%i %p');
+-------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('11:59 AM', '%l:%i %p') |
+-------------------------------------+
| NULL                                |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Formatting time works:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%l:%i %p');
+--------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%l:%i %p') |
+--------------------------------+
| 1:58 PM                        |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But formatting the time then turning it back with the same format string doesn't.

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%l:%i %p'), '%l:%i %p');
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%l:%i %p'), '%l:%i %p') |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                                    |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

As a workaround, I wound up doing:

```
mysql> SELECT TIME(STR_TO_DATE('08/07/16 11:59 AM', '%m/%d/%y %l:%i %p'));
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| TIME(STR_TO_DATE('08/07/16 11:59 AM', '%m/%d/%y %l:%i %p')) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| 11:59:00                                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The data is stored that way in a huge csv file, so editing it would be a pain. I am just wondering if this is normal or if I'm overlooking something simple.

Server info if it matters:

```
mysql> status
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.13, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:          19
Current database:
Current user:           michael@localhost
SSL:                    Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.7.13-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
UNIX socket:            /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:                 29 min 10 sec
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep in mind that there is a special `NO_ZERO_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` SQL mode which could disallow zero dates and thus let `STR_TO_DATE()` return `NULL` if you only parse a time.

Try running the following command before running `STR_TO_DATE()` with only a time:

```
mysql> SET sql_mode = '';
```

Comment: That was the problem. I didn't even think to check that behavior with that function. To avoid nuking the modes though, I use `SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'NO_ZERO_DATE', ''));`

Comment: you may also need
`SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE', ''));`