# Truncated incorrect date value: '02:02:02 am'

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

When i insert this time '02:02:02 am' to a mysql time field using the following Query:

```
insert INTO invoices(name,phone,totalsum,givenmoney,date,time,moreinfo) VALUES ('f','2','2','2','1994-01-01',DATE_FORMAT('02:02:02 am','%h:%i:%s %p'),'AA')
```

It shows the following error

```
Truncated incorrect date value: '02:02:02 am'
```

how to solve it?

Not that the datatype of my time field is `TIMESTAMP`

Comment: [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), as its name says, is used to format a date, not to parse a string into a date. The function you need is [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: @axiac if i replace it with str_to_date it say: it say `Incorrect datetime value: '02:02:02 am' for function str_to_date`

Comment: [MySQL's STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL if called with only a time component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817138/mysqls-str-to-date-returns-null-if-called-with-only-a-time-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close but you should use `str_to_time` instead

```
mysql> select str_to_date('02:02:02 am','%h:%i:%s %p');
+------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('02:02:02 am','%h:%i:%s %p') |
+------------------------------------------+
| 02:02:02                                 |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Instead of timestamp I would suggest to use `time` data type for storing the time value `H:i:s` format http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html

UPDATE :
Getting some error while running the query by SO
Here is a test case ran on mysql 5.5

```
mysql> create table invoices (
    ->    name varchar(30),
    ->    phone varchar(30),
    ->    totalsum varchar(30),
    ->    givenmoney varchar(30),
    ->    date date,
    ->    time time,
    ->    moreinfo varchar(30)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> insert INTO invoices
    -> (name,phone,totalsum,givenmoney,date,time,moreinfo) 
    -> VALUES 
    -> ('f','2','2','2','1994-01-01',str_to_date('02:02:02 am','%h:%i:%s %p'),'AA');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> select * from invoices ;
+------+-------+----------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| name | phone | totalsum | givenmoney | date       | time     | moreinfo |
+------+-------+----------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| f    | 2     | 2        | 2          | 1994-01-01 | 02:02:02 | AA       |
+------+-------+----------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

for 5.6 here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79e0c9/1

Comment: iam using INSERT statement not SELECT

Comment: Its just an example just replace `DATE_FORMAT` function with `str_to_date` inside the insert query

Comment: it say `Incorrect datetime value: '02:02:02 am' for function str_to_date`

Comment: As I said you should change the datatype of the column to `time` since you are trying to add only time to timestamp, or make the date column to timestamp and concatenate both date and time into one. But the function should work.

Comment: its still error and say `Incorrect datetime value: '02:02:02 am' for function str_to_date`
with this query `insert INTO invoices(name,phone,totalsum,givenmoney,date,time,moreinfo) VALUES ('f','2','2','2','1994-01-01',STR_TO_DATE('02:02:02 am','%h:%i:%s %p'),'AA')` whenever i have changed TIMESTAMP to TIME as you said

Comment: interesting this should not happen. Which version of mysql you are using and could you share the table definition ? Run this command `show create table invoices` and share the result into the question.

Comment: it shows only `CREATE TABLE 'invoices' (
 'id' int(11) NOT NULL ...` is that enough to share? what you want to know?

Comment: I have added some test cases both on mysql 5.5 and 5.6 please check in both cases it works !

Comment: [MySQL's STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL if called with only a time component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817138/mysqls-str-to-date-returns-null-if-called-with-only-a-time-component)